# Restricting access to certain methods in Controller classes for newly introduced Role using Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

What is the default behavior of a Controller method that doesn't have either `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_xxxx')")` or `@Secured("ROLE_xxxx")` annotation.
 Which roles are allowed to make use of these methods? Is every Authenticated user able to call those methods?

Considering the following scenario.
On an already existing application that makes use of Spring Security, we introduce an new kind of user role, i.e. "ROLE_THIRD_PARTY_CONTRACTOR" and we want them to be able to login but allow them access only to certain methods in certain Controllers. How do I restrict those users from accessing methods that don't use `@PreAuthorize` or `@Secured` annotations?

Answer (score 1):

you could try to secure at the http level before you reach the controller.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()                                                               
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/signup", "/about").permitAll()                  
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")                                      
            .antMatchers("/db/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN') and hasRole('DBA')")            
            .anyRequest().authenticated()                                                   
        .and()
        // ...
        .formLogin();
}
```

See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-httpsecurity

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will test it tomorrow. One more question, can I use this configuration to also redirect a specific role group of users from the login to a distinct page?

Comment: not sure of what kind of login you are using, but sounds like you want to do something similar to what is described in https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-redirect-login or for a more complete example: https://www.baeldung.com/spring_redirect_after_login